# When do default values in Postgres get assigned in Rails callback chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, callback

At what point in the Rails callback chain does PostgreSQL assign any database (not null constraint) default values?

For example, I have an `Experiment` model that has a `before_create` callback to set the `experiment_type`. An `experiment` has_many `Samples`. If samples have been created at the time of experiment creation, the experiment is considered the same `experiment_type` as the samples' `sample_type`. Otherwise, it gets assigned the default value of the database.

```
class Experiment < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :setup_exp_type

  def setup_exp_type
    sample_set = self.samples.first  # An Experiment has_many samples
    self.experiment_type ||= sample_set&.sample_type
  end
```

The database table has the constraint:

```
          Column           |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                        | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('experiments_id_seq'::regclass)           | plain    |              | 
...
 experiment_type           | experiment_type             |           | not null | '1'::experiment_type                              | plain    |              |
```

The controller is straightforward:

```
  def create
    @experiment = Experiment.new(experiment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @experiment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @experiment, notice: 'Experiment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @experiment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @experiment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Assuming samples have been created prior to the experiment creation and assigned to the experiment, at the point the `setup_exp_type` callback gets called, I would assume the database default values have not been assigned yet since the record is still only in local memory. However, in testing, I am seeing `self.experiment_type = 1` when debugging the second line of `setup_exp_type`. There are no other callbacks prior to this, so it is not being assigned anywhere else in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values are set when you call new on an object, you can see in the source code of the method [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class),

```rb
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 1543
      def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
        @attributes = attributes_from_column_definition
        @association_cache = {}
        @aggregation_cache = {}
        @attributes_cache = {}
        @new_record = true
        @readonly = false
        @destroyed = false
        @marked_for_destruction = false
        @previously_changed = {}
        @changed_attributes = {}
        @relation = nil

        ensure_proper_type
        set_serialized_attributes

        populate_with_current_scope_attributes

        assign_attributes(attributes, options) if attributes

        yield self if block_given?
        run_callbacks :initialize
      end
```

In the first line `attributes_from_column_definition` is called which you can check [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes_from_column_definition)

```rb
def attributes_from_column_definition
        self.class.columns.inject({}) do |attributes, column|
          attributes[column.name] = column.default unless column.name == self.class.primary_key
          attributes
        end
      end
```

As you can see in second line it is calling the column default which sets the default value of an object when it is initialised.

Comment: Very good to know, thank you

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: Both the sources provided are very out of date (rails 3.1 and rails 2.3.8)